# How union multiple and inner join in an access database in vb.net

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join, union, oledb

Dear All Master,

I have 3 tables namely SALES,SALESDETAIL,CUSTOMER. I want to combine the sales table with the sales details and also in the sales table there is a field or column "CODECUS" so I want to change it to "NAMECUST" by taking that data in the CUSTOMER table based on "CODECUS".

Thanks

```
      Dim Path As String = Environment.CurrentDirectory
    Dim cn As String = "provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=" & Path & "\ORDERS.accdb;"
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource()
Private Sub fillDataGridView1()
        Try
            Dim query As String = "SELECT * FROM SALES UNION SELECT * FROM SALESDETAIL"
            Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(cn)
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(query, con)
                    Using da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
                        da.Fill(dt)
                        da.Dispose()
                        source1.DataSource = dt
                        Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = source1
                        Me.DataGridView1.Refresh()
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

[image: SALES]

[image: CUSTOMER]

[image: SALESDETAIL]

Comment: You seem to be asking how to write basic joins in SQL. I suggest any of the many tutorials online. Starting with `INNER JOIN` to give something like `SELECT s.invno, s.dateinv, c.namecust, s.blc FROM sales AS s INNER JOIN customer AS c ON c.codecus = s.codecus`

Comment: Why are you doing a UNION of Sales and SalesDetail? What you have will fail. Probably what you really want is JOIN. Use Access query designer to get correct syntax. Access is picky about parentheses in JOIN clauses. Why does Qty look like a text field?

Comment: @MatBailie ,Thank you for your reply. but I want to combine sales details with sales and then change codecus to namecust

Comment: @June7 , `Why are you doing a UNION of Sales and SalesDetail? What you have will fail.` I'm using union doesn't show anything in DataGridView data source. `Probably what you really want is JOIN.` I want to combine sales details with sales and then change codecus to namecust Whether there is a solution or recommendation from you ?.  `Why does Qty look like a text field?` this is my fault it should be the number field

Comment: Conventional approach to 'combine' related tables would be to JOIN them on key fields. Do you not know how to build these queries? Use Access query designer.

Comment: @June7 , `Conventional approach to 'combine' related tables would be to JOIN them on key fields.` in the database it does not have a primary key but like INVNO and CUSTNO it is unique or will not double. `I want to combine sales details with sales and then change codecus to namecust` I don't know then I need guidance from you. `Use Access query designer.` Is it possible to use queries in vb.net without creating a query designer in the ms access database?

Comment: Why aren't INVNO and CODECUS set up as primary keys in respective tables? Use Access query designer to get correct syntax then transfer that SQL text to vb.net. You don't 'change' codecus to namecust, you retrieve namecust field via query joining tables. This is not the correct medium to learn basics. You should probably study some introductory tutorials on SQL.

Comment: @June7 ,   `Why aren't INVNO and CODECUS set up as primary keys in respective tables? `because this is just a view of the data. I tried with sql like this but the results can't be grouped via "INVNO" yet. `SELECT SALESDETAIL.*, SALES.INVNO, SALES.DATEINV, CUSTOMER.NAMECUST
FROM SALESDETAIL, SALES, CUSTOMER;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250177/discussion-between-june7-and-and).